# Navigation Controller not accessible within UIStoryboardSegue class

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have a custom `UIStoryboardSegue` class, and I am trying to transition views from the navigation controller, so that my navigation bar stays intact.

Currently, I am presenting the to view controllers with:

```
self.sourceViewController.presentViewController(self.destinationViewController as! UIViewController, animated: false, completion: nil);
```

I would like to use:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.destinationViewController as! UIViewController, animated: false);
```

However, I don't have access to the `navigationController` object within the Segue class. Is there any way I can access the `navigationController` variable from within this class?

Comment: To reach the superview of segue, try self.superview and why not self.superview.pushViewController(...)

Comment: @Lamasse: when I attempt this, I get an error that the class does not have a member named 'superview'. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if your controller is the first, if not then change it accordingly.

```
let nc = self.navigationController!.viewControllers!.first as destinationViewController

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nc, animated: false)
```

Comment: But I have no access to the navigationController variable, so I could not declare the variable nc this way. Do you have an alternate way to get the navigationController variable?